# ARM Assembly Syntax Highlighting in Github Gists

Tags: github, assembly, syntax-highlighting, gist, armasm

I am trying to create a Gist with appropriate highlighting for ARM (Arm7TDMI thumb) assembly code, but all of the assembly file extensions I have tried either lead to incorrect syntax highlighting or no highlighting at all. What is the proper extension for this assembly language?

Comment: ARMASM or GAS?  The syntax depends on the assembler, not just the target machine code.

Comment: @PeterCordes ARMASM is what I am looking for.

Comment: Seems like this specific version has no proper highlighting. In case you consider writing your own custom highlighting and embed it somewhere, checkout this article https://writenowdesign.com/blog/wordpress/github-gists-custom-syntax-highlighting/ about how to create a customized css for the gist highlighting.